# Python Pandas agregation

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set recording daily values of several metrics say R1, R2, for example:

```
Date     Metric cur_val     Mgmt_Lmt
1/1/2019    R1  38.94927536 100
1/2/2019    R1  38.83188406 100
1/3/2019    R1  38.71449275 100
1/4/2019    R1  38.59710145 100
1/5/2019    R1  38.47971014 100
1/6/2019    R1  38.36231884 100
```

I am trying to get the data in below format: basically agg by month year

```
    MGMT_LmtAgg Jan-19  Feb-19  Mar-19  
    100 min 80  80  80  
R1      max 90  90  90  
        avg 85  85  85  
    75  min 80  80  80  
R2      max 90  90  90  
        avg 85  85  85
```

I am trying df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='M'), 'Metric']).agg({'cur_val': ['sum', 'mean', 'min', 'last']}).T

this gives me R1 and R2 as columns, I want to see as rows. Could you help? I am beginner in python. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, welcome to DS Exchange. Have you tried to remove the transpose method? (T)
Try using df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='M'), 'Metric']).agg({'cur_val': ['sum', 'mean', 'min', 'last']}) only, if I understood correctly, you will have metric as rows.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to see Month-Year as columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the way you want to see your data is best achieved by using pivot tables.

Try the following code:

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Metric', 'Mgmt_Lmt'],
```

columns=pd.Grouper(freq='M'), 
values='cur_val', 
aggfunc=['sum', 'mean', 'min', 'last'])

This will index your table by metric and mgmt and give Month-Year as columns:

```
                               sum     mean           min     last
                 Date   2019-01-31  2019-01-31  2019-01-31  2019-01-31
Metric  Mgmt_Lmt                
R1       100            155.092754  38.773188   38.597101   38.597101
R2       100             76.842029  38.421014   38.362319   38.362319
```

By doing `df_pivoted.stack(level=0)` you will have:

```
                    Date    2019-01-31
Metric  Mgmt_Lmt        
R1           100     sum    155.092754
                    mean    38.773188
                     min    38.597101
                    last    38.597101
R2           100     sum    76.842029
                    mean    38.421014
                     min    38.362319
                    last    38.362319
```

Comment: Yup. Its working. Can't thankyou enough. Really appreciate your time trying to help others!